# Exiting from every function up to source, whilst remaining in the source

Tags: bash, function, return, exit

For example:

```
[ forrests_bash_survival_script.sh ]

#!/bin/bash
function forrest_gump() {
    echo "Something god awful happened! Run back to the source, Forrest, run."

    # Something here to exit/return from the function before terrible atrocities against Mr Gump happen

    echo "Oh god, turn back Forrest, ain't no boxes of chocolates in the black country"

    murder_forrest_gump

    echo "Sweet pumpkin pie Forrest, what have you done?"
}

function a() {
    forrest_gump

    echo "Forrest can't go here either"
    murder_forrest_gump
}

function b() {
    a

    echo "Or here"
    murder_forrest_gump
}

function c() {
    b

    echo "Or here for that matter"
    murder_forrest_gump
}
```

And now, in a separate script:

```
#!/bin/bash
c

echo "Thank God you made it back. Here's your shrimp."
```

My question is, simply, how can you return Forrest back home without him getting murdered to collect his shrimp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable `set -e` at the top of `forrests_bash_survival_script.sh`, then simply call `return 1` in `forrest_gump` before all the bad stuff starts happening, then all the functions in that file should return as soon as each has a command with a non-zero exit status.

However, I wouldn't necessarily trust Forrest's life to `set -e`; it's better to be explicit in each function and check the exit status of each call to make sure you return before `murder_forrest_gump` can be called.

Comment: *However, I wouldn't necessarily trust Forrest's life to `set -e`* - why not?

Comment: [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)